# JAXB XJC code generation issue with xs: list date and dateTime type

Tags: java, datetime, jaxb

I am using an xsd having two `<xs:list/>` elements.

```
<xs:element name="packorder1" type="DateTimeTypeXsList"/>
<xs:element name="packorder2" type="DateTypeXsList"/>
<xs:simpleType name="DateTimeTypeXsList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="DateTypeXsList">
    <xs:list itemType="xs:date"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

For these elements the JAXB generated code is :

```
@XmlList
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder1;

@XmlList
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder2;
```

The generated code does not contain any information about which one of these element is of `date` type and which one is of type `dateTime`.Now if i try to create an xml using jaxbcontext of this class it will create a dateTime element for both packorder1 and packorder2 which it should not do. So how can i distinguish between these two elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an @XmlSchemaType annotation to your model to control the output

```
        @XmlList 
        @XmlElement(required = true) 
        @XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")
        protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder1; 

        @XmlList 
        @XmlElement(required = true) 
        @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
        protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder2;
```

Also, XMLGregorianCalendar knows what XML schema type corresponds to the data its holding, see the getXMLSchemaType method on XMLGregorianCalendar:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getXMLSchemaType()

JAXB will then use that schema type to marshal the document:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Root {

        public Root() {
            packorder1 = new ArrayList<XMLGregorianCalendar>();
            packorder2 = new ArrayList<XMLGregorianCalendar>();
        }


        @XmlList 
        @XmlElement(required = true) 
        protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder1; 

        @XmlList 
        @XmlElement(required = true) 
        protected List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder2;

        public List<XMLGregorianCalendar> getPackorder1() {
            return packorder1;
        }

        public void setPackorder1(List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder1) {
            this.packorder1 = packorder1;
        }

        public List<XMLGregorianCalendar> getPackorder2() {
            return packorder2;
        }

        public void setPackorder2(List<XMLGregorianCalendar> packorder2) {
            this.packorder2 = packorder2;
        } 

    }
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();

        XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime1 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2010-07-27T12:34:56");
        root.getPackorder1().add(dateTime1);

        XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime2 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2010-03-17T01:02:03");
        root.getPackorder1().add(dateTime2);

        XMLGregorianCalendar date1 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2010-07-27");
        root.getPackorder2().add(date1);

        XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2010-03-17");
        root.getPackorder2().add(date2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <packorder1>2010-07-27T12:34:56 2010-03-17T01:02:03</packorder1>
    <packorder2>2010-07-27 2010-03-17</packorder2>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise 

Thanks for the input. But my main problem is that I dont want to change the JaxB generated classes manually. For normal Date and DateTime; the generated JaxB classes has the annotation  @XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime") or  @XmlSchemaType(name="date") properly. But for same DataType in xs:list no annotations are generated. I am looking for any solutions like a binding that will generate this annotation even for xs:list

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding you, but XJC should generate fields of type `XmlGregorianCalendar` for both `dateTime` and `date` schema types. It is up to you to know which is which; it's no different to `xs:string` and `xs:NMTOKEN` both mapping to `java.lang.String`.

Comment: yes you are right it is generating XMLGregorianCalendar for both these elements.
Actually i am also generating xml using JAXBContext of this class. I am getting dateTime default value for both date and dateTime xs:list elements.
I guess the problem is because of the missing @XmlSchemaType(name = "date") annotation in case of xs:list. How can i fix this? Do we have any such JAXB binding?

Comment: @harry: Please edit your question and add specific examples of what you're seeing, and what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Please check the question now and let me know if you need further clarification.